# Uploading entire folders to Sharepoint server 2016 without using "Open With Explorer"

Tags: document-library, drag-and-drop

Is there any way to enable drag and drop functionality to upload entire folders to a document library on Sharepoint server 2016? I know this functionality exists on Sharepoint online. So, there must be a way to enable it on the server edition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OneDrive for Business (groove) client to upload folders after synchronizing a library. There is no out of the box method to upload folders to SharePoint 2016 via browser drag and drop.

Comment: Do you know of any 3rd party add-ons? thanks

Comment: Nothing via the web UI that I'm aware of. Only sync clients such as Colligo Briefcase.